# Observable data from firebase not displaying with async pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, observable

So i am trying to access data based on an id from firebase, which returns an observable. I have logged it to the console and the Observable is there. The problem being when I try to display the data front end using the async pipe nothing is displayed. Here are my functions for accessing the data I need:

```
this.tenancy$ = this._tenancy.getUserCurrentTenancy().valueChanges();
    this.property$ = this.tenancy$.pipe(
      flatMap(tenancy => this._property.getPropertyById(tenancy.property_id).valueChanges()),
      map((property: any) => property)
    );
```

And here is how I try to access it:

```
           <div class="rent-due">£{{(property$ | async)?.rent_pcm}}</div>
```

but as mentioned, nothing is displayed. 
As a bit of extra information, I have tried doing: `*ngIf="property$ | async as property"` on the whole div, and when i do so, the entire div is removed.

Comment: I can only imagine either the `getUserCurrentTenancy()` or the `getPropertyById()` is pointing to a non existing firebase path, and therefore returning `null`

Comment: @PierreDuc when I subscribe to the property though it is there..

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a stackblitz? When I use your code with rxjs Observables instead of firebase's `valueChanges` the async pipe works.

Comment: can you check in the network monitor to see if the websocket is actually receiving data? Or just add some `tap(console.log)` before and after the `flatMap`

Comment: I know that tenancy$ is 100% receiving data, as I have that displaying front end

Comment: then you can be 100% that property is not receiving data :) otherwise it should have shown data on the frontend. You can check using `console.log` after the `flatMap`

Comment: @PierreDuc okay, so i console.log after flatMap and got nothing! Could it have something to do with the fact the tenancy$ returns an array?

Comment: @Jm3s yes, that will mean that `tenancy.property_id` is undefined

Comment: @PierreDuc okay, well it is only the [0] of the array that I need. How do I access this?

Comment: @Jm3s I've posted a solution

Answer (score 0):

After our talk, you should change your code to:

```
this.tenancy$ = this._tenancy.getUserCurrentTenancy().valueChanges();

this.property$ = this.tenancy$.pipe(
  tap(console.log),
  map(tenancies => tenancies[0]),
  flatMap(tenancy => this._property.getPropertyById(tenancy.property_id).valueChanges()),
  tap(console.log),
);
```

Comment: Still not displaying i'm afraid!

Comment: I've added some logs. Can you post the result of those logs?

Comment: Nothing is displayed